# How to access out-of-scope class?

Tags: c++, class

First of all, I would like to apologize if I used incorrect terminology in the question. I do not have any sort of formal training in programming. It was the best I could do to convey the problem.

My question is this:

In the following code structure, how can the Inventory class have complete access to Items vector inside the Player class WITHOUT making the vector static?

-- main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "World.hpp"
#include "Interface.hpp"

int main()
{
    World objWorld;
    Interface objInterface;
    return 0;
}
```

-- World.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.hpp"

class World
{
public:
    Player objPlayer;
};
```

-- Player.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Player
{
public:
    std::vector<int> Items;
};
```

-- Interface.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Inventory.hpp"

class Interface
{
public:
    Inventory objInventory;
};
```

-- Inventory.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Inventory
{
public:
    // Needs to have complete access to Items, be able to see and modify the vector
};
```

Comment: Classes do not exist at runtime. Objects do exists. Objects can have access to other objects if ypu give them a reference to that other object.

Comment: How do I pass a reference of objWorld.objPlayer to objInterface.objInventory?

Comment: Your edit completely changes the focus of the question. Please open a new question for this one. (Hint: It doesn't compile because `Inventory` is not default-constructible, and actually cannot be, as long as it has a reference member).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues which you have to consider.

1. access rights. From outside a class (i.e. from any code other than the class's member functions etc) only `public` members are accessible, except for `friend`s, which have full access.
2. visibility. In order to use a member, you must see its declaration.

Thus, you should

```
// Inventory.hpp
#pragma once
#include "World.hpp"  // makes class World visible
class Inventory
{
    World& objWorld;  // reference to 'my' world object
public:
    Inventory(World& w) : objWorld(w) {}
    void foo()
    {
        std::sort(objWorld.objPlayer.Items.begin(),
                  objWorld.objPlayer.Items.end());
    }
};
```

Of course, you must adapt the rest of your code accordingly:

```
// Interface.hpp

#pragma once
#include "Inventory.hpp"

class Interface
{
    Inventory objInventory;
public:
    Interface(World& w) : objInventory(w) {}
};
```

and

```
// main.cpp

#include "Interface.hpp"

int main()
{
    World objWorld;
    Interface objInterface(objWorld);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I do this, how should objInventory be created inside Interface? Currently not compiling.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C++ question, this is Object Oriented Programming question.

There are many ways to do this. But all of them involve more than one object working together. Either the `Player` has to have a reference (pointer) to `Inventory`, or the `Inventory` has to have a reference to player - somehow.

Here are some options:

You can pass a pointer in constructor (this is just a quick example, please use shared pointers)

```
class Inventory
{
private:
   Player *owner;
public:
   Inventory(Player *owner) : owner(owner){}
};
```

Pass it as method argument

```
class Inventory
{
public:
   void drawFor(Player *owner);
};
```

Set a field value.

```
class Inventory
{
private:
   Player *owner;
public:
   void setOwner(Player *owner) {this->owner = owner;}
};
```

As a side note, are you sure that `Player` has vector of items? I would venture that `Player` may OWN an `Inventory`. `Inventory` is more than just a vector of items. It has (potentially complex) limitations on number of items, it can maintain weight of items that affects player's movement, it can be expanded by adding containers. All of it can be useful to `Player` or `NPC`. You just have to come up with a good interface for `Inventory`

Comment: Player "owning" the inventory is indeed what I'll have to do if I can't figure out any other way to do this. Unfortunately the way my draw calls in my game are set up right now, Player drawing its own inventory would mess things up, especially when it comes to shaders that are applied to everything drawn by the World class. Could you please give me some more clarification on the "somehow" part?

Comment: @NathanielG.M. Player does not have to draw own inventory - it just has to own it. The drawing can be completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

Class members can be accessed using the member access operator `.` (period character). The left hand side is (an expression that yields) an instance of the class, and the right hand side is the name of the member.

Let `p` be an instance of `Player`. The expression `p.Items` will yield the vector of that instance. The class has to be defined, before its members can be accessed.

Comment: But in my code structure Inventory can't "see" objWorld.objPlayer

Comment: @NathanielG.M. Do you mean within a member function of `Inventory`? It would perhaps make sense then to pass a reference to the player as an argument to that member function.

Comment: Is there a way to directly modify the vector from inside Inventory instead?

Comment: @NathanielG.M. instead of what?

Comment: (I assume) instead of "carrying" the vector (passing by reference) for every change I make it to it using the main function as a medium... if that makes sense

Comment: @NathanielG.M. you really have just two choices. Either the vector (or the player that owns it, or the world that owns the player) has static storage duration, or you pass (references to) them around. You can make the reference a member variable of `Inventory` if you would like to not pass it on every member function call, but only to the constructor.